# How can I find a chord to go to after any other chord played on the piano?

Tags: piano, chords, harmony, chord-progressions, chord-theory

For example if I played a Dm triad, how would I find a/the chord this one would resolve to?

Comment: The edit MAY have altered the OP's intention: a chord can follow another chord without necessarily resolving.

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify what key you're intending this to be used in? Or are you looking to figure out where it can go as a modulation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key you are in defines the harmony, what chords you naturally have access to, and what the tonic is. From a single chord alone you cannot determine for sure either the key or the tonic, especially for a minor chord which doesn't have as strong a pull towards other chords as, say, a dominant chord.

There are a few possibilities depending which key you are in. With just Dm chord, the most likely being:

- D minor which naturally contains the chords: Dm, E<sup>o</sup>, F, Gm, Am, Bb, C
- F major which naturally contains the chords: F, Gm, Am, Bb, C, Dm, E<sup>o</sup>
- A minor which naturally contains the chords:  Am, B<sup>o</sup>, C,Dm, Em, F, G
- C major which naturally contains the chords: C,Dm, Em, F, G, Am, B<sup>o</sup>
- G minor which naturally contains the chords: Gm, A<sup>o</sup>, Bb, Cm, Dm, Eb, F
- Bb major which naturally contains the chords: Bb, Cm, Dm, Eb, F, Gm, A<sup>o</sup>

The relative modes of each of the keys above are also a possibility along with the Dm itself being borrowed, but with the  just the keys above you have access to the following chords besides Dm:

- Eb
- Em
- E<sup>o</sup>
- F
- Gm
- A<sup>o</sup>
- Am
- Bb
- B<sup>o</sup>
- C

So with just a Dm chord, you can play with any of the chords above and find what you like and then re-examine the list of chords by key and see what key fits best after you find a progression you like.

Comment: Note that Fmaj. and Dmin. have the same chord pool. Also Cmaj. and Amin. Also Bbmaj. and Gmin.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Dom's comprehensive answer, there's also Amaj., Dmaj, and Emaj., all found as dominants to the minor keys of D, G and A respectively, mentioned above. There are also chords which fit songs from the parallel keys. D minor's being D major. Thus D, Em, F#m, G, A, Bm and Co. So, for each list, change the parent key maj. to min., and vice versa. This gives a whole new set of chords. It's probably easier to state the chords which generally DON'T follow Dm !!
 Given time, later, I'll try to figure out which one or two they are !

That's without going into extended chords, with 7ths etc. As just because Dm is a triad, it doesn't mean the following chord will be...

Wouldn't mind betting, though, if you looked at 1,000 tunes with Dm, the next chord would more often than not be a G or Gm. Circle of 5ths. Of course, the notes that feature in the next part after Dm will to a large extent, dictate what that harmony will be.

Edit - using parallel maj/min., I can't find B maj. or Abmin/G#min. Seems every other maj. and min. could feature after Dmin, using that premise, although I wouldn't be surprised to find songs that it happens in.